# How to filter by column length in ODI?

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have a mapping in Oracle data integrator that works correctly, I need to filter by a column and exclude the rows where the length of that column equals 3. I can't find the correct function to do it. I already tried with `LENGTH (column) = 3` and it doesn't work...
Does anyone know the way?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Data Integrator is most of the time generating code that is pushed down to the underlying technology. So it depends which technology you are using.
For instance if you are using an IKM using the Oracle technology, the code will be execute by the Oracle database. In that case `LENGTH(column_name) <> 3` should work.

Comment: Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]'LENGTH' no es un nombre de función integrada reconocido.

Comment: My example was for Oracle as you didn't specify your database was SQL Server. A google search quickly returns that the syntax for SQL Server is `LEN(column_name)`.